# How to run below codes inside the Student.cpp through a class?

Tags: c++, header-files

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

void fillVector(vector<Student>&);
void printVector(const vector<Student>&);

int main()
{
    vector<Student> myClass;

    fillVector(myClass);
    printVector(myClass);

    return 0;
}

void fillVector(vector<Student>& newMyClass)
{
    string name;
    char grade;

    cout << "How many you students are in your class? ";
    int classSize;
    cin >> classSize;

    for (int i=0; i<classSize; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student name: ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter student grade: ";
        cin>>grade;

        Student newStudent(name, grade);
        newMyClass.push_back(newStudent);
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void printVector(const vector<Student>& newMyClass)
{
    int size = newMyClass.size();
    for ( int i=0; i<size; i++ )
    {
        cout<<"Student name: "<<newMyClass[i].getName()<<endl;
        cout<<"Student grade: "<<newMyClass[i].getGrade()<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
    }

   }

// Student.h

#ifndef STUDENT_H_INCLUDED
#define STUDENT_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
 public:
    Student();
    Student(string, char);
    ~Student();

    string getName() const;
    char getGrade() const;

    void setName(string);
    void setGrade(char);

private:
    string newName;
    char newGrade;
};

#endif // STUDENT_H_INCLUDED

// Student.cpp

#include "Student.h"

Student::Student()
{
    newGrade = ' ';
}

Student::Student(string name, char grade)
{
    newName = name;
    newGrade = grade;
}

Student::~Student() {}

string Student::getName() const
{
    return newName;
}

char Student::getGrade() const
{
    return newGrade;
}

void Student::setName(string name)
{
    newName = name;
}

void Student::setGrade(char grade)
{
    newGrade = grade;
}
```

My aim is to declare a class called CreateGradeBook inside `Student.h`and define it in `Student.cpp` and put all the code of the `main.cpp` in it. In other words I want `main.cpp` to be still there but with no codes in it like below;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
}
```

Please be tolerant if my question is inappropriate or off topic as I'm fairly new with StackOverflow. I've read FAQ section but not all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's a start

```
class CreateGradeBook
{
public:
    void fillVector();
    void printVector() const;
private:
    vector<Student> myClass;
};
```

Notice how the vector you declared in main has become a private data member `myClass`. The two functions you declared have become public methods of `CreateGradeBook`. Notice also that they have lost their parameters instead they'll now operate on the private data member `myClass`.

I'll leave you to do the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot @john for your expert answer.

I'd have gone ahead and posted the changed codes for fellow members but I thought letting them try it would be much better especially if they come up with the right changes.